# What causes can underlie the sparkContext shutting down unexpectedly?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-ml

I have a dataframe consisting of 2,818,615 rows of 388-length `pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector`s and a class label. I'd like to use the pyspark ml `RandomForestClassifier` using this dataset. Every time I attempt to train a model, spark runs for about 30 minutes before failing because the `sparkContext` was shut down. If I limit the size of the dataset to just 25K rows, the model is trained successfully, but I need to use the larger dataset.

What could be some troubleshooting steps here?

```python
print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions())   
8

df.show()
+--------------------+-----+
|            features|label|
+--------------------+-----+
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    0|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    1|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    0|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    0|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    0|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    1|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    1|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    1|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    0|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    1|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    0|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    1|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    0|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    0|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    0|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    1|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    2|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    2|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    1|
|(388,[1,355,361,3...|    0|
+--------------------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

My hardware:

- Workers: 4 vCPU, 30.5 GiB memory, 4 instances
- Master: 8 vCPU, 16 GiB memory

Here is how I (try to) train the model:

```python
rf = RandomForestClassifier(featuresCol='features', labelCol='label')
grid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(rf.numTrees, [30, 50, 75]).addGrid(rf.maxDepth, [10, 20]).build()
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="f1")
cv = SparkCV(estimator=rf, estimatorParamMaps=grid, evaluator=evaluator, numFolds=3)
cvModel = cv.fit(df)
```

The traceback claims the job failed because:

```python
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o417.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 76 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
```

Here are the final few lines of the spark log:

```python
17/11/07 23:15:04 INFO ApplicationMaster$AMEndpoint: Driver requested to kill executor(s) 31.
17/11/07 23:15:04 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 13 executor(s).
17/11/07 23:15:04 INFO ApplicationMaster$AMEndpoint: Driver requested to kill executor(s) 14.
17/11/07 23:15:04 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 12 executor(s).
17/11/07 23:15:04 INFO ApplicationMaster$AMEndpoint: Driver requested to kill executor(s) 12.
17/11/07 23:16:21 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 9 executor(s).
17/11/07 23:16:21 INFO ApplicationMaster$AMEndpoint: Driver requested to kill executor(s) 30, 18, 19.
17/11/07 23:20:07 ERROR ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
17/11/07 23:20:07 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: UNDEFINED, exitCode: 16, (reason: Shutdown hook called before final status was reported.)
17/11/07 23:20:07 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Comment: Failing at fit usually means too much data, not enough memory. Do you have any overview of the resources usage while the job is running? Additionally, can you check Spark-UI for GC and failing tasks?

Comment: @mkaran I'm not adept at navigating the spark UI, but from on the history server I see a series of `collectAsMap` jobs shuffling ~2MB of data across 8 partitions. These all run successfully until ultimately failing on a seemingly identical iteration of the same kind of job.

Comment: If you can't allocate more memory, you can try repartitioning your data

Comment: I have the same problem! Did you manage to find a solution?